# The [setstyle] tag should go out of style

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request

The [setstyle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/setstyle) tag seems to be pretty unnecessary/non-informational to me.

- There are 22 questions with this tag.
- 0 followers
- 4 questions during in the last year
- The tag wiki is empty
- With 4 questions at most it doesn't seem to be sufficiently related to any other tag to make it a synomym

Maybe I'm wrong, but it seems like nobody really knows, what this tag refers to. IMHO the tag should be burninated.

Did I miss some reason why we should keep it?

Comment: Thanks for posting this burnination request and allowing the community to take a close look at it. Please note that burninations are not just tag removals - They are the process of carefully moderating a specific place of Stack Overflow. Avoid only mass-editing the tag out of questions as it is counter-productive. Flag/vote/edit/retag the posts after consensus is reached. For more info, see [Shog9's answer on MSE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/239191/306392) or the [unofficial SOCVR process](https://github.com/SO-Close-Vote-Reviewers/SOCVR-RoomInformation/blob/master/burnination.md#process).

Comment: Why is there no pun yet for this title ...?

Comment: @Basj: Fixed :)

Comment: @fabian **We** should be burninated? Why? What have **we** done? o.O

Comment: Set fire to setstyle

Comment: @Seth Whoops... Obviously I shouldn't change the decision on using active/passive in mid sentence...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [setstyle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/setstyle) tag is now empty and is ready for the next step.

Answer (score 44):

You forgot to mention one thing: the questions tagged with it are a mashup of different languages. For example:

- JS
- CSS
- Java
- C#
- ActionScript

This isn't a reason to keep it, however. It's used in too many contexts to be useful.

You have my vote for burnination.