# User below 2k reputation burninating tag and flooding the review queue

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, burninate-system

A user is currently suggesting edits to remove the [setstyle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/setstyle) tag from different questions.

How should I handle this? I thought that burnination should always be performed after discussing it on meta and then users with 2k+ reputation editing the questions (and not by somebody under 2k).

This is what their latest revision history looks like: (and it does not list all of the revisions that got rejected as well)

[image: screenshot of revision history]

And [here](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/12316880) is a review I did of this user.

Comment: [Related burnination request](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/322728/464709). From the votes, it looks like the community green-lit it.

Comment: Okay then. The point about filling the review queue still remains though.

Comment: Yes, and they're probably only removing the tag instead of curating the rest of the posts. Just pointing out they didn't do that "on their own".

Comment: Thank you for pointing the request out. I edited my question accordingly.

Comment: As rene has shown, can @ reply editors to questions. In cases like this, ping the editor on a question one of their edits has been approved on and explain why what they're doing isn't right. In this case, you could point them to [this comment](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/322728/the-setstyle-should-go-out-of-style#comment342485_322728) on the request they appear to be working from, or to the guidelines linked in that comment. For other cases, there are other meta questions you can point them to, or even to one you created for the case.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realize that was wrong to do. I just thought to do it since there were only ~20 questions tagged. Guess I should've looked for rules before doing it. I won't do it again.

Comment: @MKII it is great that you want to help out so I would keep doing that, except that you should make sure you're not **ONLY** doing a retag. The comment on the burninating request is explaining that in a few words. If you look at [this answer of mine](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/319917/578411) among others you get an idea what we do when burninating a tag. Also see this question: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/314488/how-to-deal-with-serial-tag-only-edits-from-sub-2k-users

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Burnination is not just about removing a tag, otherwise we would have made a bot to do it. Most of the time, the post has other problems. The fire of burnination is not always destructive; it consumes posts that are not worthy, but otherwise it serves as a beacon to guide us to posts that really need to be improved.

This user doesn't seem to understand that. Looking at the post you linked, I can see a number of issues. Let me point them out:

> ## Trigger update of a tableview cellvalue without *changiing* the value
>
> `each` row contains three `cell's` with RGB values. I use these RGB values to set the background of another cell in the same row. On the `cell` that need to have the background colored`*` I have a callback which picks up the RGB values and sets the background perfectly`. So` the whole TableView `look` exactly as needed. I have a color picker and this picker needs to update the selected row containing the three RGB values. I'm able to set the new three RGB values `nut` I also need the cell with the colored background to `updated` itself to the new RGB values. In the code below I have `fount` a way to do this but I believe this is ugly. I'm `wandering` if there is a better way.

That first part is a fount of wandering errors. There is some code (which appears to be good enough), and then it ends with this nut:

> Above code last three lines triggers the updateItem of the cell but I think I'm doing this ugly

The solution is to @ping the author and to tell them that they are <s>doing this ugly</s> not fixing the rest of the post and that they need to do so. That way, they have an opportunity to change their behavior before they waste the time of more reviewers, and the ban that might result from it.

You might think that I am overly forgiving, but I think that there's a possibility that this user may just want to help, but doesn't know the rules. I think that they could become a valued editor if they are given direction.

If they take their time and fix the rest of the post, then they will not be flooding the queue to the extent that they are now. Flooding the queue is only a problem when reviewers would need to put more work into fixing the post than the original suggestion did.

---

Follow up:

It seems that I was right. The user in question, MKII, has apologized for all this trouble. From the comments:

> Sorry, I didn't realize that was wrong to do. I just thought to do it since there were only ~20 questions tagged. Guess I should've looked for rules before doing it. I won't do it again.

.....

> Re-edited the question properly this time. I will keep in mind the guidelines for the next time.

I don't think we need to worry about their edits any more.

Of course, I think that we still need to improve the system. It would be really nice if "reject and edit" could be used to teach new editors about editing (with a checkbox or something). A banner could be shown to the user the next time that they went to edit, so it wouldn't be hidden away deep within their profile.

Comment: Re-edited the question properly this time. I will keep in mind the guidelines for the next time.

Comment: @MKII That's good `:)`. I've added your comments into my answer. No hard feelings, anyway.